# Problem with Tkinter using StringVar(), trace() and Entry()

Tags: python, tkinter, trace, tkinter-entry

I am defining a `StringVar()` and giving it a value, then using it as the `textvariable` of an `Entry` widget. I have also added a trace to the `StringVar` so that I can use it as a placeholder checker and make the placeholder a different colour to the typed text.

However, when I run the code the entry widget contains no text, but if I print the value of the `StringVar()` it gives the correct value. Also, the trace command is never called and when I print the value of the `textvariable` of the `Entry` widget, it comes out as `PY_VAR#`.

Does anyone know why this is not working and how to solve it?

```
circleVarEmailAddress = StringVar()
circleVarEmailAddress.set("email address")
circletextEmailAddress = Entry(forgottenWindow, textvariable = circleVarEmailAddress,
                               font = 10, relief = "raised", highlightbackground = "black",
                               borderwidth = 2, fg = "#808080")
circletextEmailAddress.place(x = 75, y = 100, width = 250, height = 50)

def placeholderEmailAddress(a, b, c):
  print("Hey")
  for i in range(1, 13):
    if("email address"[:i] in circleVarEmailAddress.get() == True and
       "email address"[i:] in circleVarEmailAddress.get() == True):
      index1 = circleVarEmailAddress.get().index("email address"[:i])
      index2 = circleVarEmailAddress.get().index("email address"[i:])
      circleVarEmailAddress.set(circleVarEmailAddress.get()[:index1] +
                                circleVarEmailAddress.get()[index1 + i:index2] +
                                circleVarEmailAddress.get()[index2 + 13 - i:])
  if(circleVarEmailAddress.get() != "email address" and
     "email address" in circleVarEmailAddress.get() == True):
    circleVarEmailAddress.set(circleVarEmailAddress.get().replace("email address", ""))
  if circleVarEmailAddress.get() == "":
    circleVarEmailAddress.set("email address")
  if circleVarEmailAddress.get() == "email address":
    circletextEmailAddress.config(fg = "#808080")
  else:
    circletextEmailAddress.config(fg = "#000000")

circleVarEmailAddress.trace_add("write", placeholderEmailAddress)
```

Comment: What is `forgottenWindow`? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs fine for me if I add some boilerplate.

I assume from the variable name "forgottenWindow" that this is a new window in your program. The problem you are seeing can happen if you use `Tk()` to make additional windows. Always use `Toplevel` to make new windows beyond your first one.

```
forgottenWindow = Toplevel()
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. It may be because I'm using a tempermental in-browser IDE.